# recursively calculate if x is power of b

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, math

The assignment is to write a recursive function that receives 2 whole non-negative numbers `b, x`, and returns `True` if there's a natural integer `n` so that `b**n=x` and `False` if not. **I'm not allowed to use any math operators or loops**, except % to determine if a number is even or odd.
but i do have external functions that i can use. Which can add 2 numbers, multiply 2 numbers, and divides a number by 2. also i can write helper function that i can use in the main function.

this is what i got so far, but it only works if `b` is in the form of `2^y` (2,4,8,16 etc)

```
def is_power(b, x):
    if b == x:
        return True
    if b > x:
        return False
    return is_power(add(b, b), x)  # the func 'add' just adds 2 numbers
```

Furthermore, the complexity needs to be `O(logb * logx)`
Thank you.

Comment: I think you want to multiply, not add.  You also need to preserve the original value of `b` (maybe as a parameter to a helper) in order to make sure you're only increasing `n` by one each time.

Comment: @Samwise i cant add any parameters. how can i do this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible under the constraints you've described.  (I also don't think you're describing the constraints of the assignment accurately, but it's impossible for me to fix that for you.)

Comment: @Samwise maybe i can write another function that creates some kind of an index? I don't know if that possible, I'm pretty new with recursion

Comment: Writing another function that allows you to add another piece of state while still making the solution recursive is what I was suggesting, but you said you weren't allowed to do that, so I'm not sure what the path forward is.  It would be simpler to just copy the exact instructions from the assignment, since it sounds like the idea is to discover a clever loophole, and that's impossible if the instructions are being vaguely paraphrased.

Comment: @Samwise I meant that i cant add any parameters to the is_power function. I'm sorry that i was vague. Sadly the instructions aren't in English so It won't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can essentially keep multiplying `b` by `b` until you reach, or pass, `n`.

A recursive implementation of this, using a helper function, could look something like this:

```
def is_power(b, x):
    if b == 1:          # Check special case
        return x == 1
    return helper(1, b, x)

def helper(counter, b, x):
    if counter == x:
        return True
    elif counter > x:
        return False
    else:
        return helper(mul(counter, b), b, x) # mul is our special multiplication function
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. What's 'acc' in the helper function?

Comment: @MadaBit Glad it helped :) I use `acc` as accumulator, essentially we are accumulating a bunch of `b`'s into `acc` by means of multiplication. You could also call it `counter`, for example.

Comment: The time complexity of this solution does not answer to the requirement in the question.

Comment: @trincot what's the time complexity in this solution?

Comment: @trincot Doesn't it? If `b >= 2`, then isn't the time complexity *O(log(x))*? (And if `b == 1`, it's caught by the special case and is constant-time)

Comment: If we assume the time complexity of a multiplication is constant, then it is like you say. But is that true for Python integers which are dynamically sized big-integers?

Comment: @trincot Granted. I find that usually in problems that give access to blackbox functions (such as add, sub, mul here), time complexity is expressed in terms of calls to these functions though, rather than making assumptions on their inner time complexity. I suppose that's not 100% clear in this case, but I would say that his phrasing ("no math operators", "external functions") really hints towards this.

Comment: is it still O(log(b)*log(x)) if the complexity of the multipication is O(log(n))?

Answer (score 2):

Use the function you say you can use to multiply 2 numbers like:

```
power = False
result = b
while result < x:
    result = yourMultiplyFunction(b,b)
    if result == x:
        power = True
        break
print(power)
```

Question was EDITTED (can't use loops):

```
def powerOf(x, b, b1=-1):
    if b1 == -1:
        b1 = b
    if (b == 1) and (x == 1):
        return True
    elif ( b==1 ) or (x == 1):
        return False
    if b*b1 < x:
        return powerOf(x, b*b1, b1)
    elif b*b1 > x:
        return False
    return True

print(powerOf(625, 25))
```

Comment: can't use loops.

Comment: Yeah, I've just seen the update, I'm writing the solution now

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu `powerOf(1, 1)` is false :)

Comment: Sorry, it was a case I missed to add. Check the updated one

Comment: `powerOf(27, 3)` is False, but it should be True. `3**3 = 27`

Comment: You're right. I've updated the function. Basically now `b1` will keep the original value of `b`, while `b` will become everytime the function is called `b*b1`. The problem before was that I was passing `b*b` which at the second time the function was called would pass `b*b*b*b`. Ex: First time passing 3*3, Second time passing 9*9. Now it should work fine

Comment: Now it works, but one of the weird stipulations off the assignment is that the function can only take two parameters.

Comment: Oh no, It can take more, but the idea behind my code is to keep it simple for the one that uses it, this is why you create a function, to simplify the code. So I could request 3 aparameters, first would be 27, and second and third would be 3, but that woul;d be conffusing

Answer (score 1):

A solution that is O(logb * logx) would be slower than a naive sequential search

You can get O(logx / logb) by simply doing this:

```
def is_power(b,x,bn=1):
    if bn == x: return True
    if bn > x: return False
    return is_power(b,x,bn*b)
```

I suspect that the objective is to go faster than O(logx/logb) and that the complexity requirement should be something like O(log(logx/logb)^2) which is equivalent to O(log(n)*log(n)).

To get a O(log(n)*log(n)) solution, you can convert the problem into a binary search by implementing a helper function to raise a number to a given power in O(log(n)) time and use it in the O(log(n)) search logic.

```
def raise_power(b,n):                       # recursive b^n O(logN)
    if not n: return 1                      # b^0 = 1
    if n%2: return b*raise_power(b*b,n//2)  # binary decomposition
    return raise_power(b*b,n//2)            # of power over base

def find_power(b,x,minp,maxp):               # binary search
    if minp>maxp: return False               # no matching power 
    n = (minp+maxp)//2                       # middle of exponent range
    bp = raise_power(b,n)                    # compute power
    if bp == x: return True                  # match found
    if bp > x: return find_power(b,x,minp,n-1) # look in lower sub-range
    return find_power(b,x,n+1,maxp)            # look in upper sub-range

def max_power(b,x):
    return 2*max_power(b*b,x) if b<x else 1  # double n until b^n > x
    
def is_power(b,x):
    maxp = max_power(b,x)                    # determine upper bound
    return find_power(b,x,0,maxp)            # use binary search
```

*Note that you will need to convert the *, + and //2 operations to their equivalent external functions in order to meet the requirements of your assignment*

Comment: I'm not allowed to add another parameter in is_power function

Comment: Then you can make another helper function with the default parameters and call it from is_power(). You could use the opportunity to set the maxp value before calling the helper function instead of checking for maxp is None.